# Time travel book, read in 1978, based on lyrics of Scarborough Fair song

Tags: story-identification

I read this book in 1978 but can't remember title or author.Possibly a young adult novel. Plot is based on lyrics of Scarborough Fair where a young soldier from the past (Civil War?) Visits a girl in the present to perform the "tasks" of the song.

I've been trying to trace it for many years now with no luck. Searches often suggest Nancy Werlin or Rebecca Jane Curry but these are not what I'm looking for.

Comment: So, it's not [*Parsley Sage Rosemary and Time*](http://www.amazon.com/Parsley-Sage-Rosemary-Louise-Curry/dp/068950019X) ?

Comment: @JoeL. -The protagonist of that book is a young girl, not a soldier.

Comment: @Richard The OP didn't specify if the soldier or the girl was the protagonist. As written it could be either.

Comment: I'll mention Time Tangle by Frances Eagar, although the song in that one is Greensleeves. Which Civil War, by the way? In which country is this set? Do you remember anything else? Cover art?

Comment: The Devil on the Road by Robert Westall might be worth a look. http://palimpsest.org.uk/forum/showthread.php?t=4448

Comment: @JoeL. isn't that possibly the book they said it wasn't? they may have mixed up the louise and rebecca part of authors name.

Comment: Thank you for your answers-Time Tangle is the one I've been looking for (I read it as a child so must have mixed the Scarborough Fair part up with something else sorry!)I've reread it and also read the Robert Westall which I enjoyed very much.

Comment: If the question has been answered to your satisfaction, you can [mark it as accepted](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Answer (score 3):

[**Time Tangle**](http://charlotteslibrary.blogspot.com/2013/04/time-tangle-by-frances-eager-for.html) by Frances Eagar, 1976. The song is [Greensleeves](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kdjYlrvVFNo).

While staying at her convent school over Christmas, a young girl meets a mysterious young man she believes is a ghost from the sixteenth century.

See OP's comment above confirming the guess.